# Pandas filter/subset columns based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have about 300 columns that are basically encoding of categorical variables. I'd like to drop columns where `sum` of values of column is `<`, say 3.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'col1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                   'col2': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                   'col3': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'col4': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
                 })

df.sum(axis=0)
```

Expected output:

```
id col3 col4
0     1    0
1     1    1
2     0    1
3     1    1
4     1    1
5     0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` to use a boolean indexing on the columns:

```
N = 3
out = df.loc[:, df.sum(axis=0) > N]
```

If `id` is not actually numeric or if `N` can be a very large number, then maybe `set_index` with `id` first, then use boolean indexing and `reset_index` back to original:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df = df.loc[:, df.sum(axis=0)>3].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   id  col3  col4
0   0     1     0
1   1     1     1
2   2     0     1
3   3     1     1
4   4     1     1
5   5     0     0
```